# Can we have a email trigger in a pipeline and wait for someone to approve in jenkins using groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, email-ext

I have a Pipeline script where it triggers a Job A and it needs to send an email to a person and wait for his/her approval to start the next job B. The Job B needs to wait until there is a approval. This requirement is to be written in groovy script. Is there any code snippet related to this.

Comment: approve - it could be just a click on the link to input some parameter. so you need just to send an email with correct link to current job.

Comment: @daggett Thanks for the reply, I'm getting a link which opens the current build, but im wondering what's the script for aproval or rejection which will stop/continue the futher steps in the process.

Comment: Input with two choices: confirm or reject. And next step check that chosen confirm.